# GCP Firewall allow connection from cloud build to compute engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-networking

We have a GCE VM with MySQL server. Firewall rules deny incoming connections from external IP. Our cloud build process requires to perform DB migrations so it needs to connect to MySQL from Cloud Build. I want to add a Firewall rule to allow only cloud builder to connect through 3306 from the external IP address.

Cloud Build does not run on internal network so there is no way to connect from the internal IP.

I tried adding a rule for service account scope but I can't see cloud build service account in the list.

Comment: Cloud Build bridge with your VPC is in the roadmap. Today, you haven't this capability. You can try to reach the Google Support to know the Cloud Build IP range and allow only it on your firewall, but it's not very secure (anybody which use Cloud Build will have the same IP and will be able to reach your VM...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, as mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere, there is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/123374893). I recommend you to follow it (`star`) to receive all the updates there. Seems that the FR has been sent to the Cloud Build engineering team and they will evaluate it. Also note that there is not yet an ETA of the implementation.